# any big differ between $user->getAuthPassword() and Auth::user()->password? laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, if-statement, laravel, passwords

I was learning this login tutorial online with the choice for user to change password after login and the notes given are

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::route('account-change-password')
        ->withErrors($validator);
}
else
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    $old_password = Input::get('old_password');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if(Hash::check($old_password, $user->getAuthPassword()))
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        if($user->save())
        {
            return Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('global', 'Your Password has been changed');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('account-change-password')
            ->with('global', 'Your old password is incorrect');
    }
}
```

in the tutorial inside the else `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` is used right away and then the if statement to check the password is using `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);`

When I'm trying to do it on my on after watching the tutorial I did it differently.

```
if ($v->fails())
{
    return Redirect::route('account-change-password')
        ->withErrors($v)
        ->with('global', 'Please check the errors in red');
}
else
{
    if (Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'),Auth::user()->password))
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('new_password'));
        if ($user->save())
        {
            return Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('global', 'Password Changed.');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::route('account-change-password')
            ->with('global', 'Old password is incorrect');
}
```

I checked the password and the password in the database right away with `Auth::user()->password)` by using the if statement and put the `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` inside the if statement in order for me to get access to `$user->password` and change the password.

I know there are always lots different ways to do things but I'm just wondering if the way I am doing it would have some kind of problem in the future that I am not realizing it now and would be better to remember and stick to the way the tutorial taught.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you should check the source, it's within your reach so why not just dig in to deep, anyways, when you use following code:

```
$user = User::find('1');
$user->getAuthPassword();
```

This code returns the password of currently instantiated user and hence it's the user with `id=1` and it could be any user you may want, depends on you, whom to retrieve from the database. The code inside the `getAuthPassword` function is:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```

So, it doesn't matter whether the user you retrieved from the database is logged in or not. If you retrieve the user with `id=10` then you can get this user's password too.

On the other hand, the following code:

```
Auth::user()->password;
```

It returns the currently logged in user's password because `Auth::user()` returns the currently logged in user instance and this method will work only when the current user is logged in. So, yes, there is a difference in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and I do understand it but humm.....really don't know how to state my curiosity more clear.
But with these 2 cases which way would be a better recommended method to use?

Comment: @user1850712, Actually it depends on the context. Both are fine but if you need logged in user's password then use `Auth::user()`.